# Internal Link (jump to link)

Tags: html

Is it possible to add an internal link (bookmark/jumpto) on a `<button>`

```
<button class="btn span3" id="save_progress" name="save_progress" value="1">Save Changes</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link *to* any element you like. Just give the element an `id` and set the URL to `#that_id`.

If you want to link from something, use a real link. It is what links are designed for. They do it really easily (and natively, and in a screen reader and search engine friendly fashion). If you want to link from something that looks like a button, then use a link and apply CSS to make it look like a button.

If you really, really want to use a button (hint: don't). Then you can bind JavaScript to it:

```
document.querySelector('#my_button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    location = "#my_id";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Internal links don't have to point to an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

you could use JavaScript to do something like that `onclick="document.location+='#goToAnchor';return false;"`

Doesn't seem like the best practice though.